# How to find distinct rows with field in list using JPA and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, java-8

I am using Spring to connect to the db. I have an interface extending `CrudRepository<People, Long>` Here is the query I want execute on the db: `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name NOT IN UserInputSet`. I would prefer to do it without any sql annotation, so if it is possible without the `NOT` that's fine.

Is there a way to do it? I looked at the spring doc, but I cannot find anything (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

---

This is what I tired but it is not working.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name NOT IN (?1)")
List<String> findNonReferencedNames(List<String> names);
```

this is the exception I get:

```
Error creating bean with name 'peopleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List de.test.tasks.persistence.PeopleRepository.findNonReferencedNames(java.util.List)!
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: people is not mapped [SELECT name FROM people WHERE name NOT IN (?1)]
```

Comment: "its not working". Can't get clearer than that ... apart from what is happening, what error, what log, what Entity, etc

Comment: I will update the question with the error I have.

Comment: shouldn't you "colon"ise the `1` bit ?

Comment: what is entity "people" ? Should have a capital "P" ?

Comment: It's a native query. You should add `nativeQuery = true` as a parameter to `@Query`

Comment: @NeilStockton is right. Query annotation uses JPQL, not SQL.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I finally was able to figure out a simple solution without the `@Query` annotation.

```
List<People> findDistinctByNameNotIn(List<String> names);
```

Of course, I got the people object instead of only Strings. I can then do the change in java.

Comment: I have a similar requirement. I have used `List<User> findDistinctByUserName()` and it throws `NoSuchElementException` on start up. However, if if provide a parameter, it works fine but doesn't provide the result I intent. Is the parameter mandatory? How do I get the  values of whole table for a distinct column?

Comment: It may be enough for you but I think this is not making the intended query on database. This is getting distinct People instances, not distinct values of name column. In your example, this is doing SELECT DISTINCT * FROM people WHERE name NOT IN UserInputSet (which in general is not the same, unless name is a primary key) So, depending on the result desired, you may need to get the distinct names of the list of people you got.

Comment: In addition "I can then do the change in java" --- do you mean iterating over the list of people and extracting the names? If you are indeed only looking for the names and are unconcerned with the other values on `People` this would be less efficient right? You're always better off selecting as much as possible with the SQL than doing processing in Java...

Comment: @Maz: I think what you want to is to get all userNames. Just write:
Set<User> findDistinctUserName()

Answer (score 29):

Have you tried rewording your query like this?

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT p.name FROM People p WHERE p.name NOT IN ?1")
List<String> findNonReferencedNames(List<String> names);
```

Note, I'm assuming your entity class is named `People`, and not `people`.

Answer (score 11):

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name NOT IN (:names)")
List<String> findNonReferencedNames(@Param("names") List<String> names);
```

Comment: I don't think you need the parenthesis around `:names`.

Comment: When I use this, I got this error 'Column 'createdDate' in order clause is ambiguous'

Answer (score 11):

```
@Query("SELECT distinct new com.model.referential.Asset(firefCode,firefDescription) FROM AssetClass ")
List<AssetClass> findDistinctAsset();
```

Comment: distinct by which field ?

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work without using a native query:

```
List<Name> findDistinctByNameNotIn(List<String> names);

interface Name{
    String getName();
}
```

and to get the Strings use:

```
peopleRepository.findDistinctByNameNotIn().stream().filter(Objects::nonNu
ll).map(PeopleRepository.Name::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you not use like this?

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people p (nolock) WHERE p.name NOT IN (:myparam)")
List<String> findNonReferencedNames(@Param("myparam")List<String> names);
```

P.S. I write queries in SQL Server 2012 a lot and using `nolock` in server is a good practice, you can ignore `nolock` if a local db is used.

Seems like your db name is not being mapped correctly (after you've updated your question)

Comment: named params are no more or less correct than positional (though I personally would also use named).

Answer (score 0):

you can create another bean for getting the data by creating variables for each column like below.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
public static class NameOnlyBean {
    //you have to follow camelCase here when creating variables.
    private String name;
}
```

and get a list of data by using created bean like this by using your JPA query.

```java
List<NameOnlyBean> yourJPAQuery(List<String> names);
```