# Simple Distinct in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

How would you get a list/array of the distinct values in a table using JPA?

Lets say I have an entity and repository of a Foo object from a table that has columns a, b, c.  All I want is to determine all unique(distinct) values in column b where c equals "bar" and have it (the distinct values of b)returned as a list of Strings (not Foo objects).

Other ORM's I have found it very simple to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this via JPA.  It's a query that's not mapped to an object, but rather just extracting values as a simple list of Strings.

Can this be done in JPA, if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find distinct rows with field in list using JPA and Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079084/how-to-find-distinct-rows-with-field-in-list-using-jpa-and-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this simple JPQL query:

```
select distinct foo.b from Foo foo where foo.c = 'bar'
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried.  Would you mind providing the full structure with the annotation and method signature?

Comment: `@Query("select distinct foo.b from Foo foo where foo.c = 'bar'")  List<String> whateverNameYouWant();`

Comment: That's is exactly what I am following but I get: **could not resolve property: b of: com.bar.entity.Foo [select distinct foo.b from com.bar.entity.Foo foo where foo.c = ?1]**

Comment: That means that there is no property named "b" in the entity Foo. Edit your question, and post all the relevant information: the real code of your entity, the real relevant code of your repository, and the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

query is one way as said by JB Nizet

Another way with java8,   i would define these methods in repository itself. Find distinct Foos and then convert to list of b and return.Call this method with any parameter you want.

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository.. {
// name this method whatever you want
default List<String> findDistinctbs(final String b) {
    // note following is jpa convention to get list of Foos..
    List<Foo> fooList = findDistinctByb(String b);
    List<String> bList = fooList.stream().map(Foo::getB).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return bList;
}
```