# Distinct counting with Spring JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Now I'm counting views of topic something like this:

```
Long countByViewOnTopicId(Long topicId);
```

This is equivalent to SQL query

```
select count(*) from views where topic_id = ?
```

This gives me the number of all views, but I need to count the number of unique users. I need JPA equivalent of below query:

```
select count(distinct user_id) from views where topic_id = ?
```

I can use the `@Query` annotation, but I'm trying to write less custom SQL in the project. Like below:

```
Long countDictinctUserIdByViewOnTopicId(Long topicId);
```

**Update:**
`Below entry details:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "views")
public class Views {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "topic_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long topicId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "topic_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Topic topic;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "action_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private ActionTypes actionType;

Getter, Setter...
```

Comment: I assume that `Long countDictinctUserIdByViewOnTopicId(Long topicId);` is not working. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you post your entity-classes? What is the target entity class of your repo and how is it connected to user? If your entity has `User user` field, try to use `countDictinctUser` instead of `countDictinctUserId`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079084/how-to-find-distinct-rows-with-field-in-list-using-jpa-and-spring

Comment: @Syn, maybe `countDistinctUserIdByViewOnTopicId` does, instead :-S

Comment: @YCF_L is it a question? The docs say it is possible to use derived count queries: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ Are there any references for the case with `distinct`?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I don't have any reference I remove my comment until I found one

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
criteriaQuery.multiselect(criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(root));
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria