# JPA dynamic fields of Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have Object Laptop with fields brand, model and size and 12 more fields
Is it possible using JPA to build query with dynamic setting fields?
For example
"Select param1 From Laptop"
where param1 can be brand,model,size etc

Answer (score 0):

If you have to extract distinct values of fields check this question
[How to find distinct rows with field in list using JPA and Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079084/how-to-find-distinct-rows-with-field-in-list-using-jpa-and-spring)

Even if you need to read a single field of an entity, load the entire in as fast as a portion, since network transfert time is much smaller than disk access time. You can use eventually a stream().map(Lapto::getParam1)

for other reason you have to use a raw solution involving EntityManager. getCriteriaBuilder()

(try to be more specific)

Comment: Network transfer time is NOT generally faster than Disk Access time. It depends in your connection. Iterating over 20000 items in a list may be slower than execute a simple Webrequest which returns only the needed value, yes, but even that depends in the connection. Database calls are very pricy.

Comment: My solution: Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select " +param1 +sep+param2+sep+param3+sep+ param4+sep+ param5+ " From Laptop");
Where params are method params, and sep is separator :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new custom method in the repository interface (which you will call to perform queries), and you have several options:

- You have the option to construct a 'handcrafted' String by concatenating the select statement. However, it is crucial to be cautious of the SQL Injection threat:

> "select " + param1+ "from table"

Subsequently, you can supply the string to the @Query annotation within the repository to generate a native query with your SQL

```
@Query(value = "Here goes the string", nativeQuery = true)
```

- You can explore more in-depth functionalities by leveraging specific APIs, such as the Criteria API

P.S. I don't know the specific reason behind your request, but indeed, if your records have few fields and are not too complex, you can comfortably keep the query that retrieves the entire object and then work on the fields that interest you.